# Index of notations grouped by where they appear. How to implement?

Tags: symbols, glossaries, makeindex

I want to create an index of notations that looks like the following one
[image]
So the entries are sorted and grouped by where they appear. However, the usual list provided by `glossaries` has each entry in a single line and location at the end of that line.

**Question: how to implement an index of notations like above?**

**Update** I find that all the information I need is already stored in the `.sls` file and there is an in-line style for glossaries. So I have an idea:
Consider the following preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[symbols,automake,counter=subsection]{glossaries-extra}
\newcommand{\mygls}[2]{%
  \glsxtrnewsymbol[description={}]{#2}{\ensuremath{#1}}%
  \gls{#2}%
}
\newglossarystyle{mystlyle}{⟨definitions⟩}
\makeglossaries
```

Here ⟨definitions⟩ should be the correct definition of `mystlye`, which I don't know how to implement.
Suppose the main body is

```
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{A subsection}
  Let $\mygls{\mathcal{C}}{C}$ be a cat and 
    $\mygls{\mathfrak{S}_{\mathcal{C}}}{SC}$ be the Sym-bundle over $\mathcal{C}$.  
    blabla...
    Let $\mygls{\mathbb{X}[\mathcal{C}]}{XC}$ denote the above construction and consider the following $\mygls{\mathbb{Y}[\mathcal{C}]}{YC}$    
    ...
\subsection{Another subsection}
  Let $\mygls{\mathcal{M}}{M}$ be a mod on $\mathcal{C}$ and 
    $\mygls{\mathfrak{S}_{\mathcal{M}}}{SM}$ 
    blabla...
    Let $\mygls{\mathbb{X}[\mathcal{M}]}{XM}$ denote the above construction and consider the following $\mygls{\mathbb{Y}[\mathcal{M}]}{YM}$    
    ...
\section{Second section}
\subsection{A subsection with no new entry}
\subsection{Yet another subsection}
  Blabla... $\mygls{\mathbb{Z}^1}{Z1}$ ... $\mygls{\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}\otimes\mathcal{M}}{T}$ ... $\mygls{\mathbb{H}}{H}$

\printglossary[type=symbols,style=mystlyle,title={Index of Notations}]
\end{document}
```

Then I should get the following output:
[image]

To achieve this, one needs to

1. grouping the entries by their location counters,
2. customize the display of the glossary so that each group is in a single item of the list.

**Any idea to implement these?**

**Update:** Add a more detailed example.

Comment: Could you add a small but complete example document to your question, with, e.g., two subsections and a few notation entries, that generates an index using `glossaries`? That would save time for people interested in answering to get started, and it would also ensure that the solutions match your setup and can be used in your actual document.